# Accessing AppWidgetHost to launch the 'Add Widget' activity from within my program's activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

I would like to add the ability for a user to launch the *Add Widget* activity to choose my application's widget to add to their phone's homescreen from within my application.

I was following this example: [Android:NPE while trying to activityForResult with ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573966/androidnpe-while-trying-to-activityforresult-with-action-appwidget-pick-intent), but realized that I didn't have the homescreens `AppWidgetHost`.

I know I need to use the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK`, but Android Developer says that I need to launch this from within my `AppWidgetHost`.  If I am trying to get the appwidget onto the homescreen, this implies that I need to gain access to that instance of the `AppWidgetHost`.  How would I get access to that or get that instance?  Is it even possible to do anything with the homescreen's `AppWidgetHost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I get access to that or get that instance?

You can't. That's not in your process.

> Is it even possible to do anything with the homescreen's AppWidgetHost?

Only if you are the home screen in question.

> I would like to add the ability for a user to launch the Add Widget activity to choose my application's widget to add to their phone's homescreen from within my application.

AFAIK, this is not supported.